# Print steps of sort

Tags: java, sorting

i was wondering of it is possible to print out every step of the sort. Here is my code:
as you can see, i pass in a linked list, the values of i copy to an array to possibly make my sorting life easier and then write the sorted array to a separate text file.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Insertion 
{
    public void Sort (LinkedList listIn, int size) throws Exception
    {
        String[] insArray = new String[size] ;
        String textContent = null ;
        File outputFile ;

        //copy the list values in the array
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        {
             insArray [i] = listIn.get(i).printNode();
        }

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch().start(); 

        //Insertion Sort
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if (insArray[j-1].compareToIgnoreCase(insArray[j]) > 0)
                {
                    replace(insArray, j, j-1);

                }
            }

         timer.stop();   

         do
            {
                outputFile = new File("[Insertion] Sorted Entries.txt") ;

                    if(!outputFile.exists())
                    {
                        outputFile.createNewFile ();                    
                        System.out.println("Sorted file created.txt");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("File Updated.");
                    }

            }while (!outputFile.exists()) ;

        try
            {

            //the "true" argument sets the FileWriter to append mode so that is does not overwrite the first line
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("[Insertion] Sorted Entries.txt", true));
                for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
                {
                    textContent = (insArray[i]) ;
                    out.write(textContent) ;
                    out.newLine() ;
                }

                out.close() ;
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Could not write to file") ;
                System.exit(0) ;
            }

         System.out.println("Time to execute: " + timer.getElapsedTime() + "ns"); 
    }

    private static void replace(Comparable[] array, int i, int j) 
    {
        Comparable swap = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to work out a hypothesis that would explain both the fact that you wrote this code and the fact that the code already clearly shows how to log each step of the algorithm. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Have another loop within for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) which prints out all elements of the array

Comment: To me the question is not totally clear. Do you mean print the state of the insArray after every sorting step? Like adding the code to write the contents of insArray to a file or stdout before calling replace?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik im failing to see something here?! yes i wrote the code with the help of a friend. and its not easy to spot everything after working 12 hours straight

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for the weary eyes... would something like this be helpful?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            final int cmp = insArray[j-1].compareToIgnoreCase(insArray[j]);
            System.out.format("Comparing %s at %d to %s at %d, result %d\n",
               insArray[j-1], j-1, insArray[j], j, cmp);
            if (cmp > 0) replace(insArray, j, j-1);
        }
```